# InDesign: Using GREP to style URLs, email addresses, phone numbers, social handles, and hashtags

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, grep

I'm brand new to GREP and its uses in InDesign, and while I'd like to understand it in a more robust way someday, at the moment I'm struggling to find some resources that can explain just the basics to me in a comprehensible way.

So, **Question #1:** If you happen to know of such resources, it would be awesome if you could point me toward some. Keep in mind I am a designer not a coder, so if the resource is riddled with coding jargon like "shell" and "escapes" and "environment variables in the regex" I am not going to have any idea what those words mean. I can generally grasp coding principles pretty well but I don't know the vocab.

**Question #2:** Can someone tell me how to write a GREP expression that will target any grouping of characters containing a period with letters and/or numbers on either side of it, but no space? I am looking to target URLs, email addresses, and phone numbers, and our house style writes those as the following:

url.com

emailaddress@email.com

000.000.0000

What I want to do is make it so that line breaks never happen in the middle of these "words." I know it involves creating a character style with the No Break setting and then using a paragraph style to apply the character style using GREP, but I don't know how to write these parameters in GREP. Targeting anything between spaces that has a period should work but I don't know how to write that.

**Question #3:** Can we write a second expression targeting social handles and hashtags? So that would be any word starting with a @ or # that may or may not have numbers and/or an underscore in it. If it is followed by any punctuation before the next space *aside from an underscore*, I would like the punctuation to not be included in the expression. (So , . ! ? — - should not be included in the expression but _ should.) This should probably distinguish social handles from email addresses by specifying that a social handle will always have a space before the @ (whereas an email address would not), but I would prefer the preceding space to not be part of the selection.

**Bonus!:** I would *love, love, love* it if these answers could come with explanations for *why* they work and what they're doing. I'll still love answers that solve my problem and teach me nothing in the process but that's only 1/3 of my available love. Teach a man to fish and all that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The best resource I know for beginning to understand how to use GREP in InDesign is the InDesign Secrets website.  They have an entire resources section about using GREP, and I believe there are articles linked there that specifically address writing GREP for all three of the situations you address in your Question 2.  And I know they have at least one article all about setting certain types of text as "no-break."

You can find this information here:  https://indesignsecrets.com/resources/grep

There is quite a bit of explanation as to why certain GREP works the way it does in the various articles listed here, but I also struggle with this issue.  So another great resource that helps me is http://regexr.com/. It is a sight specifically designed to help you learn to use GREP--you can write GREP codes and get immediate feedback about what they are doing, and there is a tab called "Explain" that actually tells you what each section of your expression actually means.

I still struggle with using GREP, but these two resources have been really helpful in allowing me to develop better skills.

Answer (score 1):

GREP Find/Change and GREP Styles will change your life. :) I was in the same boat as you about 2 years ago. magerber gave the same resources that I would have suggested. I went ahead and wrote the expressions that you are looking for.

I find URLs to be little difficult because they are less predictable. I often have to tailor my expression to the document that I am working in. If your urls truly are as simple as you say then this should get you started but it will likely need some fine tuning.

url.com

(\w+.[\l\u]{3})

Same story with emails.

emailaddress@email.com

\w+@(\w+.[\l\u]{2,3})

000.000.0000

(\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4})

Answer (score 0):

If you have an email address like some of ours in the UK it will look like

emailaddress@email.co.uk

And the GREP expression above won't pick up the .uk

So I use:

\w+@(\w+.[\l\u]{2,3}.[\l\u]{2,3})

This seems to work with *both* .co.uk (and e.g. .ac.uk) as well as .com

Answer (score 0):

I just use
<(http|www)\S+

That seems to work for me.